# What should the type of the return value of the key function in sort() be?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, the `sort` method of `list`s accepts a `key` parameter which is a function.

My question is, what constraints are there on the returned value of `key`? Should it be a numeric value? Should it be somehow comparable? Or does every type of value just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only constraint set is that the return values should be comparable; they should support `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` and `==` tests.

In Python 2, *everything* is comparable with everything else, making the restriction rather moot.

In Python 3, there are more restrictions on what makes values comparable; comparisons between objects of different types are not supported, for example, so you don't want to return a mix types.

Note that this is not anything special to the `key` function; the same restrictions apply to the values being sorted, see the [Comparisons documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). All that the `key` function does is let you provide a 'stand-in' value to sort on instead of the actual value at a given position.

Comment: "comparisons between objects of different types are not supported" -> Actually, this isn't quite true; the built-in types don't support it, but it's perfectly feasible to write your own class that knows how to do it.

Comment: @kindall: sure, I was simplifying for the sake of a readable answer here.

Answer (score 1):

In py2.x you can return anything you want, but in py3.x you'll get errors if you return different types of values(objects) because you can't compare two different type of objects in py3.x

[Docs:](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)(py2.x):

> The operators `<`, `>`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, and `!=` compare the values of two
>   objects. The objects need not have the same type. If both are numbers,
>   they are converted to a common type. Otherwise, objects of different
>   types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but
>   arbitrarily.
>
> In the future, the comparison rules for objects of different types are
>   likely to change.

Py2.x:

```
>>> x = [1, '2', [3]]
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
[1, [3], '2']
```

Py3.x:

```
>>> x = [1, '2', [3]]
>>> x.sort()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    x.sort()
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

[What's new in python3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> The ordering comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`) raise a `TypeError`
>   exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering.
>   Thus, expressions like `1 < ''`, `0 > None` or `len <= len` are no longer
>   valid, and e.g. `None < None` raises `TypeError` instead of returning
>   `False`. A corollary is that sorting a heterogeneous list no longer
>   makes sense – all the elements must be comparable to each other. Note
>   that this does not apply to the `==` and `!=` operators: objects of
>   different incomparable types always compare unequal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The key function is simply a function that is applied to each element before sorting (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/). It isn't actually a comparison function (which I think is what you're getting at).

If you're comparing objects in some custom way, you'll want to define a set of 'rich comparisons' (I think this blog post covers it quite nicely http://regebro.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/python-implementing-rich-comparison-the-correct-way/).

Comment: I know what the key function is. Read the question properly.